# Creating a dynamic web project with maven in eclipse and running it on server

Tags: java

When I created a dynamic web project with maven in eclipse and Tomcat server then it showed "Hello World". My question is there in index.jsp file saying "hello World" but I couldn't find it being added in "web.xml" file.
 How is it working without adding it to the web.xml? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is how JSPs work.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has its default "web.xml" in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf, if a mapping is not found in your project "web.xml", it will search the default one.

Take a look at that file, you will find:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also it has a default welcome file list:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```